# Absolutely positioned img didn't stretch the parent?

Tags: html, css

Link demo: http://codepen.io/leoaivy/pen/adxJaR
As you can see in the link above, the first square's child didn't stretch its parent while the second square's child did. I think it's because the image has its ratio itself, so we can't change it by position absolute. Is it right?

html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parent img, span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.parent span {
  background: gold;
}
```

Comment: add a `max-width: 100%;` for the image

Answer (score 0):

You can force the image to stretch by adding `height:100%; width:100%;`

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parent img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent img,
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.parent span {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <span></span>
</div>
```