# Why absolutely positioned img cannot be auto stretched?

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

If the `height` & `width` of an absolutely positioned element is not explicitly declared, and all of the 4 directions are `0`, then the element will get the same `height` & `width` as its containing block:

CSS

```css
section {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: teal;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

HTML

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

BUT things seem strange when it comes to the **`img`**:

CSS

```css
section {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: teal;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  background-color: pink;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

HTML

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <img src="" alt="">
  </section>
</body>
```

Nothing changed except I replaced the `div` with the `img`. I even gave the `img` an explicit `display: block`, which is obviously redundant since absolutely positioned elements are computed as `block`. BUT the `img` didn't be stretched as the `div` did. Inspected it and found that the `img` exactly got the `height` 400px of its containing block, `section`, but **the `width` is 0**.

So here is my questions: Why absolutely positioned `img` cannot be auto stretched?

NOTICE: The `img` has no content.

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453958/absolutely-positioned-img-didnt-stretch-the-parent), but I want the most essential and theoretical explanation rather than a workaround.

Comment: it's a replaced element so you need width:100% and height:100%